# What is the format of the data you can write to a SourceDataLine?

Tags: java, audio, javasound

In java you can create a SourceDataLine like so:

```
AudioFormat af = new AudioFormat(AudioFormat.Encoding.PCM_SIGNED, 44100.0, 16, 1, 2, 44100.0, false);       
SourceDataLine sdl = AudioSystem.getSourceDataLine(af);
```

After which you can open and then write data to it:

```
byte[] data = new byte[1024];
fillwithsounds(data);

sdl.open()
sdl.start()
sdl.write(data, 0, 1024);
```

This all works fine for mono data.

What I'd like to do is to be able to write stereo data, and I can't find any documentation online on how I need to change my byte array to be able to write stereo data.

It seems like I need to increase the amount of channels when I create the AudioFormat - to make it stereo - and then I need to half the framerate (otherwise Java throws an IllegalArgumentException)

I don't understand why this is though, or what the new format should be for the data that I feed to the DataSourceLine.

Perhaps somebody with a little more experience in audio formats than I could shed some light on this problem. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm theorizing that instead of the byte array consisting of Mono-Frame, Mono-Frame, Mono-Frame. The byte array should now consist of Left-Frame, Right-Frame, Left-Frame, Right-Frame, Left-Frame, Right-Frame. I tried to implement that, but instead of giving me anything sensible, it gave me static.

Comment: *"After which you can open and then write data to it:
This all works fine for mono data."*  OK you are nearly there.  Whatever you write for each 16 byte frame in the original format, ..write it twice.  That is effectively 'mono through two speakers', but if you have something different to write to the other channel, write that instead.

Comment: *"I tried to implement that, but.."* For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The format I use for stereo is as follows:

```
        audioFmt = new AudioFormat(AudioFormat.Encoding.PCM_SIGNED, 
            44100, 16, 2, 4, 44100, false);
```

You probably want to double the bytes per frame instead of halving your bits-encoding. I'm not sure what 8-bit encoding sounds like, but it is definitely going to be noisier than 16-bit encoding!

The resulting file is twice as long. You can then take the two-byte pairs that make the 16-bit sample and copy them into the next two positions, for "mono" playback (both stereo channels identical).

Given:

```
frame = F
little end byte = A
big end byte = B
AB = 16-bit little-endian encoding
left channel = L
right channel = R
```

Your original mono:

F1A, F1B, F2A, F2B, F3A, F3B ...

Stereo using the above format:

F1AL, F1BL, F1AR, F1BR, F2AL, F2BL, F2AR, F2BR, F3AL, F3BL, F3AR, F3BR ...

I could very well have the order of left and right mixed up. But I hope you get the idea!

Comment: Thank you, I wrote this function to implement your theory, but I'm getting an extremely weird result: http://pastebin.com/L86ZmXrg
I'm using exactly the AudioFormat you mentioned in the first line of your answer. I'll write a new comment with my definition of "an extremely weird result"

Comment: To see "an extremely weird result" compare http://home.coolkev.com/BeforeProgram.mp3 to http://home.coolkev.com/AfterProgram.mp3

Comment: Pastebin function looks OK. I brought the two files into Audacity. It says they both use 32-bit encoding (not 16) and are marked mono. Thus, your original file uses 4 bytes per frame not 2. Did you set the output format to have 2 channels? Why was the result MONO? I don't know how to convert 32-bit to 16-bit in Java. I use Audacity for complicated conversions (beyond mono to stereo or vice versa). You might be able to expand the loop to increment i by 4 and transfer 4 bytes in each (and adjust the output format accordingly, to 2 channels and 8 bytes per frame) and retain 32-bit encoding.

Comment: I'm sorry, Those files were recordings of the playbacks. I'm not sure how exactly to write back to a file from Java but I can look into that.

Comment: Well, then, it would be helpful to verify the following: show us the format of the data of the original wav file, show us the format used for the SDL. Need to double check that all the values line up as expected!

Comment: What do you refer to by the SDL. I am uploading the original wav now.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a little slow tonight, I initialize the SDL with:`AudioFormat af = new AudioFormat(AudioFormat.Encoding.PCM_SIGNED, 44100, 16, 2, 4, 44100, false);` and then `outputline = AudioSystem.getSourceDataLine(af);`

Comment: Did you get it to work? I noticed you accepted my answer. It looks like from what you confirmed that the original wav and the format you used are as it should be. If it is still sounding weird, I'll try coding up the conversion myself and sharing the results with you. (Am wondering how you are reading the original wav.) P.S.: I assumed that since you make your own byte[] to hold the entire wav that you are doing some sort of manipulation? Otherwise, there are easier ways to input. BTW, have you read this? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/converters.html

Comment: I haven't gotten it to work yet, but your answer is the correct answer to my question so I accepted it. And yes, I will be doing some sort of manipulation, but this is currently commented out.

Answer (score 0):

I found out the solution just now, and found Andrew Thompson's comment to explain exactly what I needed.

I figured that I'd have to write each frame twice, what caught me up was the fact that Java wouldn't let me just use the frame size I had for my mono channel. (It threw an IllegalArgumentException)

So I halved the framerate to satisfy Java, but I didn't remember to modify the byte array.

I've implemented code that takes the "2 bytes per frame, 1 channel" byte[] and converts it into a "1 byte per frame, 2 channel" byte[].

```
private static final float LEFT   = -1;
private static final float CENTER = 0;
private static final float RIGHT  = 1;

private byte[] monoToStereo(byte[] data, float pan){
    byte[] output = new byte[data.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < (data.length - 2); i+=2){
        int currentvalue = (data[i+1]*256 + data[i])/(256*2);
        if (pan == LEFT || pan == CENTER){
            output[i] = (byte) currentvalue;
        } else {
            output[i] = 0;
        }
        if (pan == RIGHT || pan == CENTER){
            output[i+1] = (byte) currentvalue;
        } else {
            output[i+1] = 0;
        }
    }
    return output;
}
```

Using this, I can get stereo audio to playback (although there is soft static, I can clearly hear the original track)